# Encode content as CDATA in generated RSS feed

Tags: ruby, rss, cdata

I'm generating an RSS feed using Ruby's built-in RSS library, which seems to escape HTML when generating feeds. For certain elements I'd prefer that it preserve the original HTML by wrapping it in a CDATA block.

A minimal working example:

```
require 'rss/2.0'

feed = RSS::Rss.new("2.0")
feed.channel = RSS::Rss::Channel.new

feed.channel.title = "Title & Show"
feed.channel.link = "http://foo.net"
feed.channel.description = "<strong>Description</strong>"

item = RSS::Rss::Channel::Item.new
item.title = "Foo & Bar"
item.description = "<strong>About</strong>"

feed.channel.items << item

puts feed
```

...which generates the following RSS:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Title &amp; Show</title>
    <link>http://foo.net</link>
    <description>&lt;strong&gt;Description&lt;/strong&gt;</description>
    <item>
      <title>Foo &amp; Bar</title>
      <description>&lt;strong&gt;About&lt;/strong&gt;</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Instead of HTML-encoding the channel and item descriptions, I'd like to keep the original HTML and wrap them in CDATA blocks, e.g.:

```
<description><![CDATA[<strong>Description</strong>]]></description>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

monkey-patching [the element-generating method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/rss/rss.rb#L257-278) works for me:

```
require 'rss/2.0'

class RSS::Rss::Channel
  def description_element need_convert, indent
    markup = "#{indent}<description>"
    markup << "<![CDATA[#{@description}]]>"
    markup << "</description>"
    markup
  end
end

# ...
```

this prevents the call to [`Utils.html_escape`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/rss/utils.rb#L89-105) which escapes a few special entities.

Comment: That's _way_ cleaner than the solution I ended up going with, even if it is a monkey patch.

Comment: `class RSS::Rss::Channel::Item` is the class that worked for me, on Ruby 2.3.